# How do I tunnel/use a proxy server with SSH? (open failed: connect failed: Connection refused error)

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to set up tunneling and I'm testing by trying to a ubuntu iso (torrent instead of http). On my machine I'm using

```
ssh -4 -g -N -D 127.0.0.1:7123 root@rpi_addr
```

I'm getting errors and not able to download anything

> channel 14: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused

From my understanding -4 forces everything to be ip 4 (my isp doesn't offer ipv6), -g should allow connections from my server to me, -N means I don't want/need to execute any shell commands and -D is where the socks server should be at? I have a feeling this might be a UDP problem but I'm not sure. Especially since it's saying Connection refused

If it matters, my host pc is windows 10. I tried using ssh that comes with windows 10 and with git-bash. The server I'm connecting to is a raspberry pi

Comment: (1) "I'm getting errors" – When? Just after you invoke `ssh`? or when you try to use the proxy? (2) What are the errors from? From the `ssh`? (3) What program with what settings are you using to actually test the connection? (4) "`-g` should allow connections from my server to me" – If you mean "from the pi to the Windows 10" then possibly not in the way you mean. Are you sure you want a socks proxy? (5) Please read this: [How to create a SOCKS proxy with `ssh`](https://superuser.com/a/1308648/432690).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski 1) when I start the torrent to download ubuntu. It downloads nothing and prints many of these. 2) The shell that I executed the ssh line on 3) qbittorrent, not sure why that would matter. 4) Does my line not allow both windows and linux to open ports to eachother?

Comment: (1) `Connection refused` means the SSH server could not connect to the requested address on the behalf of the SOCKS client. I guess it's not unusual when torrenting because some trackers or peers may no longer be at their former addresses. (3) I wanted to make sure the program can actually use SOCKS. Your statement about "connections from my server to me" made me suspect you were confusing things. (4) `-g` could allow other clients in your LAN to use the `7123` port of your local machine as a SOCKS proxy. I think `-g` is irrelevant in your case because you bind to `127.0.0.1` anyway.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I'm not sure whats happening but I can browse websites just fine but not peer to peer

Answer (score 0):

Say, you have a server, with SSH, and MySQL.

```
ssh -L 3336:127.0.0.1:3306 root@rpi_addr
```

Then calling MySQL on your local host will be tunneled to rpi_addr's localhost interface... More here: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-setup-ssh-tunneling/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the remote host to be able to use the SSH channel to access a SOCKS server and not the other way around. I think that you need to use the -R option for this kind of thing, not -D.